# module insertion in beagle board

Tags: linux, module, beagleboard

I am trying to insert a .ko module to beagleboard c3. I cross compiled the module using arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc. But on inserting the module to beagle board( having linux 2.6.28-OMAP1)  using insmod , it is showing an error

> invalid module format

Normal files are running with out any problem.(executable of c program). what could be the problem. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: When a module load fails, an error message for the failure will appear in `dmesg`. Include that error in your question for more detailed assistance.

Comment: on dmesg ,it is shown that "no symbol version for struct_module"

Answer (score 0):

You need to build uImage and modules at the same time ie. after building uImage you need to build modules and together put on the board.